# How to use babel-runtime in Babel 6?

Tags: node.js, babeljs

I'm trying to create npm module and I can't find single instruction on official babeljs website. How do you use babel-runtime package? From name I'm guessing it should be placed in "dependencies" section of package.json, right?

Absolutely no information here: https://github.com/babel/babel/tree/master/packages/babel-runtime

Found one example here: https://strongloop.com/strongblog/javascript-babel-future/ but when I run "babel -h" it doesn't list --optional as a valid parameter.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The runtime is optional, but like everything else in Babel 6, it is primarily enabled by adding a plugin. In this case, you need http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-runtime/

```
plugins: ["transform-runtime"]
```

- `babel-runtime` is a package that contains a polyfill and many other things that Babel can reference. You'd install it in your app with `npm install babel-runtime`
- `transform-runtime` is a Babel plugin to process your source code and inject `import foo from "babel-runtime"` statements so that `babel-runtime` is actually used. You'd also install this with `npm install babel-plugin-transform-runtime`.

Comment: Then what is the different between 'transform-runtime' plugin package and 'babel-runtime' package? How can I verify that this is working?

Answer (score 45):

## Rationale

When transpiling your code, Babel will actually inject helpers to emulate features not supported by the ES version you target.

For example: [`class MyClass {}`](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015&experimental=true&loose=false&spec=false&code=class%20MyClass%20%7B%7D) leverages the inline helper `_classCallCheck`, which can also be accessed through `require('babel-runtime/helpers/classCallCheck')`.

By default, those helpers are not shared between the compilation units (the files). The Babel team though it might be interesting to factorize them in one place, allowing to save space when they are used multiple times.

This issue has been addressed by creating the `babel-plugin-transform-runtime` plugin, which walks the AST and replaces the helpers injections by the appropriate requires of the `babel-runtime` module. That way the helpers are shared across the codebase and the duplication is avoided.

## How to use it

Assuming you have a [running Babel environment](https://babeljs.io/docs/setup/):

1. Install [`babel-plugin-transform-runtime`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-transform-runtime) (as a `devDependency`), which transforms your code to remove the helpers and uses the ones in `babel-runtime`. *You need to add it to the `plugins` array of your Babel configuration*
2. Install [`babel-runtime`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-runtime) (as a `dependency`), which is the actual library `babel-plugin-transform-runtime` assumes you are going to have in your `dependencies`, it will be used by your transpiled code at runtime. *You do not need to require it anywhere in your code.*

## Minimal snippet

- `npm run build` compiles the `lib` folder into `dist`
- `npm start` starts the `dist` folder (which depends on `babel-runtime`)

*package.json*

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "build": "babel lib --out-dir=dist",
    "start": "node dist"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-runtime": "^6.9.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.10.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.9.0"
  },
  "babel": {
    "plugins": [
      "transform-runtime"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi @aymericbeaumet, I think your answer assumes a node environment. Is that correct? If so, what should be done in a browser environment (without the node backend)? Are any of the runtime items needed?

Comment: @Zander: do you mean run babel _in_ the browser?

Comment: hi @aymericbeaumet, let me clarify: I meant when transpiling es6 code to be run in the browser (e.g. gulp/grunt/webpack etc) not using babel to transpile on-the-fly. Does that make sense?

Comment: @Zander: if you don't enable the babel-plugin-transform-runtime tranformation, you won't need babel-runtime to be included in the bundle. It's up to you to make the choice, both will work the same for code being transpiled either in node or in the browser (on-the-fly).

Comment: this should be the correct answer as it explains the why and how of babel-runtime